# How can we update a duplicate row and then delete it using vba?

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

VBA novice and got 90% of the way to what I need but I just can't figure out the final part. For the last step I have a range of data from A:K, with A containing a unique number. An updated version of this data is pasted below the initial range with the numbers in Column A staying the same, but B:K being updated.

**How can i copy the duplicate row below, paste it over the original above, and then delete the duplicate?**

```
Sub TEST2()
'
' TEST2 Macro
'

'   Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:K1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$L$20").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="red"
Range("a2").Select

Dim LR As Long
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A2:K" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A2").Select
Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

ActiveSheet.Range("A1:l100").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 1), Header:=xlYes


End With
Range("$q$1").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("H2:H1000").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Worksheets("Sheet1").ShowAllData
Range("O3").Select

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("O3").Select

End Sub
```

At the moment i can only get as far as using this to delete the duplicates. There are other elements to the sheet which require it to be done this way. 
Thanks in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>First thought after seeing the issue... it's a little more than a single line:</s>

```
Dim i as integer, LR as Long
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 to LR 'Assumes that row 1 is headers
    If Application.Match(Cells(i,1),Range(Cells(2,1),Cells(i-1,1)),0)>0 Then
        Rows(i).Cut
        Rows(Application.Match(Cells(i,1),Range(Cells(2,1),Cells(i-1,1)),0)+1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Else
        End If
    Next i
```

Edit:  It's not liking the range; I will try cleaning it up, then use insert/delete... keep in mind, if we're using delete for any row, you'll want to reverse the step, as to avoid issues.  See below changes, noting that *j* is added:

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, LR As Long
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = LR To 3 Step -1 'Assumes that row 1 is headers
    If Application.IfError(Application.Match(Cells(i, 1), Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(i - 1, 1)), 0), 0) > 0 Then
        j = Application.Match(Cells(i, 1), Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(i - 1, 1)), 0)
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 11)).Cut
        Range(Cells(j + 1, 1), Cells(j + 1, 11)).Insert xlShiftDown
        Range(Cells(j + 2, 1), Cells(j + 2, 11)).Delete
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: Thanks for both the replies! I'm trying to avoid adding a helper column or sorting so I've tried to implement Cyrils code. For some reason I keep getting the error: pastespecial method of range class failed, whether i add this to my existing code or as stand alone test. I've tried all sorts to no avail. I've added my code to the question for viewing. Also if i could make one amendment to the original question- instead of cutting/copying the whole row, can we just cut/copy the cells from A:K please. Many thanks!

Comment: @jay123 Try it now; I did some testing, and that should do you right for only columns A:K

Comment: That works an absolute treat, Much appreciation Cyril! Its even made some of the the original formatting code redundant so I've deleted that whole section - much neater. On a final note you mentioned that we'll need to reverse a step when deleting rows, what does this mean exactly?

Comment: @jay123 Look at the "For i" statement.  I call out "Step -1" and we go from LR to 3.  In general, "Step 1" is used, which means it goes in order 1 by 1; saying "Step -1" allows you to go in reverse order and from the last row to the first row (numerically).  When you move/delete a row, the last row can change, so to avoid issues, you go in reverse.  Hopefully that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below algorithm (with illustrated example as below) :-

1. Create a column to store sequential number for sorting purpose
2. Perform the sorting so that the latest appended rows are always at the top. Excel's removeduplication function will always keep the first encountered unique value
3. Once done, you can perform sorting to re-order the rows of data again.

Below is a sample code which you will need to modify based on your actual dataset.

```
Sub Test()

    LastRow = Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("L1").Value = LastRow
    Range("L2").Value = LastRow - 1
    Range("L1:L2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("L1:L" & LastRow)
    Range("A1:L" & LastRow).Sort Order1:=xlAscending, Key1:=Range("L1"), Header:=xlNo
    Range("A1:L" & LastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 1), Header:=xlNo

End Sub
```